# EAS build development for IOS fails on Pods install

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, eas

I hope someone can help me, when i try to build an app using expo with the command  eas build --profile development --platform ios, it gives me the error below "The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries: ...". This happens only on IOS, android is working fine, i try to look for a solution but didn't find a lot of information regarding this issue...

Any solution ?

This is the error message in the expo logs.

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

The Swift pod `FirebaseStorage` depends upon `FirebaseStorageInternal`, `FirebaseAppCheckInterop`, `FirebaseAuthInterop`, `FirebaseCore`, and `FirebaseCoreExtension`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

pod exited with non-zero code: 1
```

[Printscreen of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9y0a.png)